# Javascript error retrieve data from JSON object

Tags: javascript, json

In my project i create an object when an input text blur like this:

```
inputT1.onblur = function(){
            var pDomain = this.value;
            if (pDomain.substring(0,4) === "http") {
                var getLocation = function(href) {
                    var l = document.createElement("a");
                    l.href = href;
                    return l;
                    };
                var l = getLocation(pDomain);
                pDomain = l.hostname;

            }

            responseT = $.get( "neuroscan/php/trial500.php", { P1: 'dominio', P2: pDomain } );
            console.log("Status: "+responseT.responseText);

            }
```

Console respond Status: undefined 
and if i write:

```
console.log("Status: "+JSON.parse(responseT.responseText));
```

return an error.
The object responseT was create (as you can see from the picture) and responseText have a value, but I can't isolate it into a variable

[image]

Any idea?

Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to return the response from an Ajax call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call)

Comment: I read that post but my problem is that despite the existence of the object responseT if I write responseT.responseText console me back "undefined"

Comment: responseText  filled when request become complected. So when you call console.log at first time - it is undefined. But it filled later

Comment: Your problem is that you're testing them at different times. When you type "responseT" in the console it has already been resolved. But when you have `responseT.responseText` in the code, it hasn't been resolved yet and you're accessing promise. The duplicate will solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$.get return promise, not data. Thus it work ansyncroniusly

```
inputT1.onblur = function(){
        var pDomain = this.value;
        if (pDomain.substring(0,4) === "http") {
            var getLocation = function(href) {
                var l = document.createElement("a");
                l.href = href;
                return l;
                };
            var l = getLocation(pDomain);
            pDomain = l.hostname;

        }

         $.get( "neuroscan/php/trial500.php", { P1: 'dominio', P2: pDomain }, function(data, status, xhr){
                 console.log(data);
               });
        }
```